# jvisualvm is not available in JAVA_HOME/bin directory in Fedora

Tags: java, java-8, jvisualvm

I've installed java 8 in Fedora 28 OS.
I read that I don't need to install it separately it is bundled with jdk.

But `jvisualvm` option is not present in JAVA_HOME/bin directory.

Below are the files in bin directory.

```
$ ls
appletviewer  idlj  jarsigner  javac    javah  java-rmi.cgi  jconsole  jdeps  jinfo  jmap  jrunscript  jstack  jstatd   native2ascii  pack200     rmic  rmiregistry  serialver   tnameserv  wsgen     xjc
extcheck      jar   java       javadoc  javap  jcmd          jdb       jhat   jjs    jps   jsadebugd   jstat   keytool  orbd          policytool  rmid  schemagen    servertool  unpack200  wsimport
```

Java details  -

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.31.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_181-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.31.0.1-linux64) (build 25.181-b02, mixed mode)
```

The fedora version is -

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
  Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
```

Why I don't have jvisualvm command in come with java 8 installation?

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/questions/514323/where-is-the-visualvm-executable-for-linux

Comment: @moilejter that’s outdated. The new source is https://visualvm.github.io/